# Clear form after submit React

Tags: reactjs

In my app, I am making a form to add animal for adoption with React. The data is stored in Mongo if this is important to know.

But I can not figure out how, I tried to look and nothing works for me. Maybe there is something wrong with the form. I would be very thankful if someone can tell me how to clear or reset the form after submitting. I simplified it so it would be easy to see what I have. Here is my form:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { addAnimal } from "../redux/actions";

const AddAnimalForm = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [kind, setKind] = useState("");
  const [displayForm, setDisplayForm] = useState(false);

  const dispatchAddAnimal = () => {
    dispatch(
      addAnimal(
        {
          name,
          kind
        },
        "_id  name kind sex age city author phone info"
      )
    );
  };

  const onShowButtonClicked = () => {
    setDisplayForm(true);
  };

  const onHideButtonClicked = () => {
    setDisplayForm(false);
  };

  return !displayForm ? (
    <button className="col-xs-12 col-md-3" onClick={onShowButtonClicked}>
      add
    </button>
  ) : (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <button className="col-xs-12 col-md-3" onClick={onHideButtonClicked}>
          hide{" "}
        </button>
        <form>
          <div className="form-row">
            <div className="form-group col-md-6">
              <label htmlFor="animal-name">name</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
                id="animal-name"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group col-md-6">
              <label htmlFor="kind">kind</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                onChange={e => setKind(e.target.value)}
                className="form-control"
                id="kind"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <button
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-primary"
            onClick={dispatchAddAnimal}
          >
            add animal
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default AddAnimalForm;
```

Comment: There are some errors on the code, looking into it.

Comment: @inv its mixup of  uncontrolled and controlled form.Use either one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a variable at the top just below you imports

```
let exampleRef = React.createRef()
```

hi first you have to create a reference to that form like this  :-

```
<form ref={(el) => myFormRef = el;}>
  <input />
  <input />
  ...
  <input />
</form>
```

and after that, while submitting your form you just use the ***reset()*** method provided by the form reference like this

```
 const dispatchAddAnimal = () => {
   myFormRef.reset();  
   dispatch(
    addAnimal(
      {
        name,
        kind
      },
      "_id  name kind sex age city author phone info"
    )
  );
 };
```

let me know if it works for you or not.

> there is also a great library [React Advanced Form](https://redd.gitbook.io/react-advanced-form/) which handle lots of thing on its own like validation and other stuff check this out if you feel free

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set property 'myFormRef' of undefined

Comment: you have a stateless component not stateful so you need to change something in it. I edited the answer above now it will work for you